# Smoothing M-splines

Tags: r, math

I'm currently approximating the baseline function required in a model using Msplines of order `d=4`:

```
r(t)=γ1 M1(t|4,x)+...γp Mp(t|4,x)
```

To avoid local fluctuation, I would like to penalized the likelihood by penalizing the curvature of the baseline function.

```
l(O)-∫r''(u)^2du
```

My problem is I don't know how to calculate the following part in R: `∫r''(u)^2du`

I've found that `∫r''(u)^2du = γT Ωγ`

Where `Ω=∫M''(u)M''(u)du`

Where `M''` is the second derivative matrix of M-splines.